# Stream Audio into THREE scene

Tags: javascript, audio, three.js, html5-audio

I'm trying to load a streaming audio source (the audio is live) and attach it to a THREE scene object for positional audio. It looks like the right module to use is `THREE.AudioLoader` using its onProgress callback, but I can't find any examples of how to handle streamed audio, only preloaded audio sources that use the onLoad callback.

Does anyone know the right way to make this work?

Comment: the [AudioLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/AudioLoader.js) working on XmlHttpRequest and response does'nt seem to mention anything of streamed audio support in docs

Comment: I looked into that and couldn't find anything, either. Was wondering if there's something about it that I didn't know about - maybe using part of the undocumented API (AudioListener, etc.)

Comment: 2nding nivendha's comment. I was also looking into this requirement and it's likely not possible with THREEJS built-in support. However it seems you might be able to use base Web Audio API as a workaround with a bit of tinkering: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/games/#toc-3d